# Undefined Range Value

Tags: javascript, html, css

For context, I'm just learning JS. On my web-page, I want to have the option to create new range-inputs that are interactive. I also want to use the values of the ranges for an equation. Right now, I can add the ranges themselves fine, and they work, but the values of each range returns as `undefined`.

I found this out while trying this in JavaScript:

```
document.addEventListener('input', function(event) {
    if(event.target.matches('.range')) {
        console.log(event.value);
    }
})
```

Also, here is the code I did for creating new Range Inputs:

```
function addSolvr() {
    solvContain = document.querySelector('.solveContainer')
    const solvDiv= document.createElement('div');
    solvDiv.className="rangeContain"
    solvContain.appendChild(solvDiv);
    const solvLabel = document.createElement('input');
    solvLabel.classList.add('form-label', 'rangeLabel');
    solvDiv.appendChild(solvLabel);
    const solvAssist = document.createElement('input');
    solvAssist.type="number";
    solvAssist.className="rangeAssist";
    solvAssist.value = 0
    solvDiv.appendChild(solvAssist);
    const solvRange = document.createElement('input');
    solvRange.type = "range";
    solvRange.className="range";
    solvDiv.appendChild(solvRange);
}
addBtn.addEventListener('click', addSolvr)
```

Is there a way to get the accurate value from each range? It may be helpful to know that I was able to do this before, but that was with static elements. This time, I'm using appendChild() for creating the range. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting undefined, because there is no value property in the event.

To access the value of the element, you have to use `event.target.value`. That way you're getting the value of the targeted element. Like so...

```
document.addEventListener('input', function(event) {
    if(event.target.matches('.range')) {
        console.log(event.target.value);
    }
});
```